# Doxygen : how to use EXPAND_AS_DEFINED

Tags: c, doxygen

I have defined the following macros, and try to have it expanded when generating documentation.

```
#define GETSET(param) \
bool CYNOVE_Enable##param(postproc_ctx_t ctx, bool enable)  \
{                                                           \
 struct postproc_ctx * c;                                   \
 c = (struct postproc_ctx *)ctx;                            \
 c->do_##param = enable?1:0;                                \
 return TRUE;                                               \
}                                                           \
```

In doxygen, if I use :

```
MACRO_EXPANSION = YES
```

Then the macro is expanded when I use it.
However if set :

```
MACRO_EXPANSION = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF = YES
EXPAND_AS_DEFINED = GETSET
```

the macro is not expanded

Since I think, one of the answer is wrong, but the comment just suck for any lengthy explanation, let me add how I think this should work.

According to the doxygen documentation and this [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-learningdoxygen/), PREDEFINED and EXPAND_AS_DEFINED serve different purpose. I understood that EXPAND_AS_DEFINED is used to selectively expand a given macro "as it was defined in the source code", hence the name, while PREDEFINED is here to give Doxygen the meaning of a macro.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is as the name says, it will only expand predefined macros if put that way. You should put something like

```
PREDEFINED += GETSET(param)="..."
```

in your Doxygen file.

BTW, since you are using `bool`:

- `enable?1:0` should just be `enable`, `bool` are nothing else than `0` and `1` in C.
- `TRUE` should be `true`

Answer (score 0):

I tested it using the questioner's configuration options, and the macro expanded normally. I don't know if the doxygen update has fixed this issue.

My version: A tool to configure and run doxygen version 1.9.4 on your source files.

t.c

```
#define GETSET(param) \
bool CYNOVE_Enable##param(postproc_ctx_t ctx, bool enable)  \
{                                                           \
 struct postproc_ctx * c;                                   \
 c = (struct postproc_ctx *)ctx;                            \
 c->do_##param = enable?1:0;                                \
 return TRUE;                                               \
}          

GETSET(123)


#define CONST_STRING const char *

CONST_STRING version = "2.xx";
```

[image]
[image]

---

In addition, you can use `-d preprocessor` to check what the code looks like after macro expansion.
[image]

Comment: doxygen version 1.9.4 is a bit older, the current version is 1.10.0.